# Scala: Extracting tuple values when iterating

Tags: scala, dictionary, functional-programming, pattern-matching, scala-collections

Say I have this map: `Map[String, Int]`

In order to iterate over its values, I have to do this:

```
myMap.foreach(t => {
    val word = t._1
    val number = t._2
    //do stuff with word and number here
})
```

Is there a way to do something like this instead:

```
myMap.foreach( (word, number) => {
    //do stuff with word and number here
})
```

Using scala 2.13.2 atm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use pattern matching:

```
myMap.foreach { case (word, number) => ... }
```

or for:

```
for((word, number) <- myMap) {
  ...
}
```

Comment: I don't love calling methods without parenthesis. Reduces the readability. Is there a way to use `case` within paranthesis, e.g `myMap.foreach(case (x,y) {} )`? p.s i used foreach as an example, I want to be able to use this on all higher order functions (map, flatMap, zip, etc)

Comment: @ClickUpvote all these higher order functions behave the same. Unfortunately I don't know any other possibility except for the `for` expression

Comment: @ClickUpvote you can surround all the expression in parethensis like: `foo.map( { case (key, value) => bar })` but nobody does that. Most **Scala** programmers would agree that would be less readable.